# Symfony2 Sluggable does not exist or could not be autoloaded

Tags: mongodb, symfony, slug

I've been trying to get an existing project working on local copy but have been countering alot of problems with the ODM and the dependencies.

I'm encountering this Sluggable issue :

```
[Semantical Error] The annotation "@Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation\Sluggable" in property       
Cereals\ProductBundle\Document\Category\Specialty::$name does not exist, or could not be 
auto-loaded.
```

And my Cereals...\Specialty file is such:

```
<?php
namespace Cereals\ProductBundle\Document\Category;
use Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\Annotations as MongoDB;
use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;

/**
* @MongoDB\Document(collection="Specialty",    
repositoryClass="Cereals\ProductBundle\Repository\SpecialtyRepository")
*/
class Specialty
{
/**
* @MongoDB\Id(strategy="auto")
*/
protected $id;

/**
 * @Gedmo\Sluggable
 * @MongoDB\Index(order="asc")
 * @MongoDB\String
 */
protected $name;

/**
 * @MongoDB\String
 * @MongoDB\UniqueIndex
 * @Gedmo\Slug
 */
protected $slug;

/**
 * @MongoDB\String
 */
```

I understand from Googling that there are some syntax updates for doctrine 2.1.x and I've used the new annotations for the @Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation\Sluggable here too.

Still the Semantical Error turns up.

Can anyone point some directions ? Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `@Gedmo\Sluggable` annotation does not exisit. If you look in this [folder](http://github.com/l3pp4rd/DoctrineExtensions/tree/master/lib/Gedmo/Mapping/Annotation), you will see this anottation is not implemented.

Actually, You can define your class like that:

```
<?php
namespace Cereals\ProductBundle\Document\Category;
use Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\Annotations as MongoDB;
use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;

/**
* @MongoDB\Document(collection="Specialty",    
repositoryClass="Cereals\ProductBundle\Repository\SpecialtyRepository")
*/
class Specialty
{
    /**
    * @MongoDB\Id(strategy="auto")
    */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @MongoDB\Index(order="asc")
     * @MongoDB\String
     */
    protected $name;

    /**
     * @MongoDB\String
     * @MongoDB\UniqueIndex
     * @Gedmo\Slug(fields={"name"})
     */
    protected $slug;
}
```

The `@Gedmo\Slug` annotation needs the properties which will be used for the slug generation.

Comment: Hi Gelo , Thank you for your reply ! May I clarify with you that with the new updates , @Gedmo\Sluggable no longer exists and I can omit it from my $name but include the "name" field into the @Gedmo\Slug from now onwards ?

Comment: Like describe in the [documentation](http://github.com/l3pp4rd/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/sluggable.md), it's the only way.